# How to define camel blueprint connection factory

Tags: xml, spring, apache, jboss

I'm new to camel and active mq . i'm using jboss fuse and i have crerated a queue in fuse console , and i have made a camel blue print with osgi in jboss developer studio . in the blue  print i have slite csv records and send the recored one by one to queue. but i'm getting  connectionFactory must be specified error . can any one fix me ???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
            xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
            xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0"
            xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
            xmlns:blueprint="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

      <bean id="transactionManager"
             class=
"org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class=
"org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL"  value=
"tcp://IYC6ITDT1:61616?maximumConnections=1000"/>
    </bean>

  <bean  class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
    </bean>
  <camelContext trace="false" id="blueprintContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
     <route>    
        <from uri="file:C:/Users/thomasalbert/workspace/uyirnokkam/input"/>
        <unmarshal>
            <beanio mapping="isha/mdm/uyn/participant-datamapping.xml" streamName="participantFile"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <split>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <marshal>
                <json library="Jackson"/>
            </marshal>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
            <log message="This is the JSON record: ${body}"/>
            <to uri="jms:queue:Thomas"/>
        </split>
    </route>
</camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the jmsComponent bean id is not defined, please give the id as "jms" as shown below

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Also, this id is used to access the queue in the below line

```
<to uri="jms:queue:Thomas"/>
```

So if the bean id is "sampleJMS", then the endpoint changes to "sampleJMS:queue:Thomas"

This should resolve the current error, but again there are some more errors in your code.

Example : maximumConnections cannot be passed as argument in brokerUrl, instead use pass it as a parameter with a PooledConnectionFactory as explained in http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html#ActiveMQ-Usingconnectionpooling